# How to initialise a class constructor using inversify which has other dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

**config.ts**

```
export const bindings = new AsyncContainerModule(async (bind) => {
  await getDbConnection();
  await AppSubscribers;
  await Locators;
  await RouterClass;

  bind<AppSubscribers>(TYPES.AppSubscribers).to(AppSubscribers);
  bind<Locators>(TYPES.Locators).to(Locators);
  bind<IRepository>(TYPES.IRepository).to(Repository);
```

**locator.ts**

```
import { inject, injectable } from 'inversify';
import TYPES from '@shared/di/types/types';
import Locator from '../.Locators';
import { AfterTypeCreated } from './AfterTypeCreated';
import { logger } from '@shared/core/logger/logger';
export class AppSubscribers {
  constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.Locators)
    private locators: Locators
  ) {
    logger.info('SUBSCRIBER STARTED');
    new AfterDataCreated(this._locators);
  }
}
```

AppSubscriber needs to inject Locators which further injects Repo and other services.

I need to initialise app subscriber at the start of the application to add all the subscribers (observers) to the registry.